# psql loop in shell script

Tags: sql, postgresql, shell, for-loop, psql

I need to read from a file.csv 2 values and make more then 13.000 queries in a PostgreSQL.

It should be very simple task as you may see in the code above, but there are some issues.

```
#!/bin/bash


MSISDN=($(head file.csv | awk -F ";" '{print $1}' | sed -e "s/^/55/"))
APPID=($(head file.csv | awk -F ";" '{print $3}'))

NUMBER_OF_LINES=$(wc -l file.csv| grep -o "[0-9]*")

for i in $(seq 0 "$NUMBER_OF_LINES")
do

    export PGPASSWORD='MY_PASSWORD'
    psql -q -A -h VERY-LONG-HOST -U MYUSER -d DATABASE -p 1111 -t -c "select 'http://API-HOST/subscription/cancel?subscriptionId=' + s.subscription_id + '&phone=' + s.phone + '&enabled=0&statusId=7&notifyActionListeners=false&extraInfo=TICKET_NUMBER' from sbs.subscription s (nolock) join sbs.configuration c on s.configuration_id = c.configuration_id where c.application_id = ${APPID[$i]} and c.carrier_id = 2 and s.phone = ${MSISDN[$i]};"

done
```

when the code executes there is a error:

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "112940676229"
> LINE 2: and c.carrier_id = 2 and s.phone = 55112940676229;
> ```

How can I work with multiples queries and close the connection in each of them before make another query, thus far how to solve the error showed before?

Example of the content in file.csv:

```
112940676229;Sevice;333                                               
113429402012;Sevice;929  
111429402013;Sevice;888
11240672940;Sevice;445
11320294034;Sevice;333
11429294056;Sevice;22
11942940281;Sevice;122
11962940895;Sevice;233
```

Comment: please add couple of lines of file.csv to the post

Comment: @VaoTsun The  content of the file.csv is added

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: Short form: Don't try to read `file.csv` into your arrays ahead-of-time; rather, read it line-by-line, and process each line as you go.

Comment: BTW, using string substitution to form SQL commands is prone to injection vulnerabilities. If you didn't build that CSV file yourself, by hand, I **strongly** advise against this approach -- you'd be much safer using a language that lets you use bind variables so you can pass data to your database engine out-of-band from code. Related: https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: (Also, running `psql` 13,000 times is going to probably cost more than the queries themselves do; using a more appropriate programming language -- such as Python -- is a good idea for performance as well as security).

Comment: Aside from everyone's comment/concerns, I'd suspect the csv contains carriage returns.

Comment: @alvits, a fair possibility; amended my answer to take them into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both security and performance, I **strongly** advise using a different language for this. That said, to answer the narrow question:

```
while IFS=';' read -r msidn _ appid _ <&3; do
  appid=${appid%$'\r'} # fix DOS newlines, should they be present in your input
  psql -q -A \
    -h VERY-LONG-HOST -U MYUSER -d DATABASE -p 1111 -t \
    -c "select 'http://API-HOST/subscription/cancel?subscriptionId=' + s.subscription_id + '&phone=' + s.phone + '&enabled=0&statusId=7&notifyActionListeners=false&extraInfo=TICKET_NUMBER' from sbs.subscription s (nolock) join sbs.configuration c on s.configuration_id = c.configuration_id where c.application_id = $appid and c.carrier_id = 2 and s.phone = $msidn;"
done 3< file.csv
```

---

That said, a less-awful Python implementation might look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import csv
import sys
import psycopg2

query='''
select
  s.subscription_id,
  s.phone
from
  sbs.subscription s (nolock)
  join sbs.configuration c on s.configuration_id = c.configuration_id
where
  c.application_id = %(appid)s
  and c.carrier_id = 2
  and s.phone = %(msidn)s
'''

# user is expected to pass CSV file name as our first argument
filename = sys.argv[1]

# user is expected to pass a PostgreSQL connect string as our second argument
conn = psycopg2.connect(sys.argv[2])

curs = conn.cursor()

with open(filename, 'rb') as csv_file:
  csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';')
  for csv_row in csv_reader:
    msidn = csv_row[0]
    appid = csv_row[2]
    curs.execute(query, {"msidn": msidn, "appid": appid})
    for result_row in curs.fetchall():
      sid = result_row[0]
      phone = result_row[1]
      print 'http://API-HOST/subscription/cancel?subscriptionId=' + sid + '&phone=' + phone + '&enabled=0&statusId=7&notifyActionListeners=false&extraInfo=TICKET_NUMBER'
```

Comment: Hi @Charles Duffy, ok I had implement the Python code how ever I got this error:
curs.execute(query, (appid,msidn))
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

I tried to cast the varibles
 msidn = int(csv_row[0])
 appid = int(csv_row[2])

but with no success, I had give up the shell script because as you said it is too much agressive for this purpose.

Comment: Ahh. Sorry 'bout that, didn't match up the two param styles.

Comment: You'll still need the cast to `int` **if** the column types are integer -- I don't know what they types are since you didn't include the schema in the question. (If you'd included SQL to generate the schema and insert test data to fulfil the "Verifiable" part of the [mcve] definition, then this answer could have actually been tested).

Comment: @ Charles Duffy Sorry for my lack of experience too much time without posting here.

Comment: NP, it happens. Anyhow -- with the edit above (`curs.execute(query, {"msidn": msidn, "appid": appid})`), is the code behaving better?

Comment: Hi @Charles Duffy Thanks so much for your help 1 more thing:
curs.execute(query, {"msidn": msidn, "appid": appid})
ValueError: unsupported format character '
' (0xa) at index 179
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Same error  with the new edit (curs.execute(query, {"msidn": msidn, "appid": appid}))

Comment: @Daniel, actually -- any chance you changed the `%(foo)s` syntax to take out the `s`s on the end? That would explain the error perfectly.

Comment: To be clear, I *do* think you'd be better off with @VaoTsun's approach. Much more efficient to just do one query rather than one per line.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you trying such approach:

```
create table file_csv (tel bigint, dk text, apid int);
copy file_csv from file.csv delimiter ';';
```

and then just join against it in your query.

**update** Thanks to @Charles Duffy

Might make it a temporary table (`create temporary table file_csv (tel bigint, dk text, apid int)`), if the intent is to be transient.

Comment: Excellent call. Might make it a temporary table (`create temporary table`), if the intent is to be transient.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy hi from shell script I recived error:
ERROR:  column "112940676229" does not exist in s, c, unnamed_join

Comment: @Daniel, questions about my answer should be comments *on my answer*, not on someone else's. (And please provide output of running `bash -x thescript` to allow debugging).